# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$servername' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) php

Tags: php, database

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database usign PHP but am currently facing this error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$servername' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in line 4.`

Here is my code :

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "anything";


    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB;charset=utf8', $username, $password); //connexion à MySQL
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 
        $stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT Place, Address, Date FROM MyDB"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        die('Connection failed:' . $e->getMessage()); //En cas d'erreur, on affiche un message et on arrete tout
        }
    }

        $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM myDB'); //récupération de tout le contenu de la table MyDB
        // On affiche chaque entrée une à une
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
?>
    <p>
    <strong>Name</strong> : <?php echo $donnees['Place']; ?><br />
   </p>
<?php
}

$reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête

?>
```

I've been googling this mistake already but could not find anything relatable. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This question is not meeting community guidelines..   Iif you want to connect database with pdo then this link will help you  https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

You try following code.

```
<?php
class DBClass {

    protected $servername = "localhost";
    protected $username = "root";
    protected $password = "anything";

    public function run()
    {
        try {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->servername.';dbname=myDB;charset=utf8', $this->username, $this->password); //connexion à MySQL
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully";
            $stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT Place, Address, Date FROM MyDB");
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die('Connection failed:' . $e->getMessage()); //En cas d'erreur, on affiche un message et on arrete tout
        }

        $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM myDB'); //récupération de tout le contenu de la table MyDB
            // On affiche chaque entrée une à une
        while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
        {
        ?>
            <p>
            <strong>Name</strong> : <?php echo $donnees['Place']; ?><br />
            </p>
            <?php
        }

        $reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête
    }
}

$obj = new DBClass();
$obj->run();
```

Answer (score -2):

remove

```
class DBClass {
```

or you have to implement this in OOP way.

https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_connect.asp

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123";


    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB;charset=utf8', $username, $password); //connexion à MySQL
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 
        $stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT Place, Address, Date FROM table1"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        die('Connection failed:' . $e->getMessage()); //En cas d'erreur, on affiche un message et on arrete tout
        }


        $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM table'); //récupération de tout le contenu de la table MyDB
        // On affiche chaque entrée une à une
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
?>
    <p>
    <strong>Name</strong> : <?php echo $donnees['Place']; ?><br />
   </p>
<?php
}

$reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête

?>
```